# Auto populate TO field for send an email button

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, email2case

I have created a custom "Send an Email" button using the URL below for case Object.  Is there a way to add to this to Auto-populate the "To" field to be the email address from Custom object?

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!Case.Id}
&p4=stephen.price@com.com
&p24= test@email.com
&p26=testemail@test.com
&rtype=003
&retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}
&p2_lkid={!Case.custom_object__c}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JS `location.search` to access the url query and inject it into your text value

If your url is `/page.htm?x=y`, you can use the following code to set the value of a text field.

```
var params = getUrlParams();
document.getElementById('myTextFieldId').value = params.x;
```

Comment: Thanks @Adamo, I need populate multiple email address to TO field not from url.

Comment: Please mark the post as helpful if I actually help you :D